# Alamofire with Swift using a Get

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire with Swift 5 and using a get to send some parameters while a Post works the following fails, any idea of how this should be used. If I remove the parameters it works .

```
let parameters:Parameters = ["SiteKey": "abcdef"]
AF.request(url, method: .get,parameters:parameters,encoding: JSONEncoding.default,headers:headers )
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It's clearly implied from the results that you've got. A `GET` request cannot contain parameters in its body, a `POST` request can. Get request should be something when you paste the `URL` in a browser and you should get the response in the browser.

In your case it's either not `GET` request or you need to send the parameters as `url-encoded`.

```
AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .queryString), headers: headers)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I amended the code as this is a get: AF.request(url, method: .get,parameters:parameters,encoding: URLEncoding.default,headers:headers ) to URLEncoding but this still seems to fail. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I tried but cannot get this to work, this works fine in Postman